# Spring Data JPA filter Data in subclass with own query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am working on a little JAVA project to improve my work with passwords. For this i use a H2 database to store the data and Spring data JPA as OR-Mapper. All DML operation works fine, but I do not want to allow the user to delete passwords from the database. For this I add a field in the Bean named DML_ART. The DML_ART is a string field, which is the state of the row. For example, if the user clicks on the JSF GUI on delete, the flag will set to "DELETE".

On the load of the data this line is to ignore. The SQL Query Works for DBPasswordEntity, but the subclass has also to filter by the same criteria.

But the written statement is not valide. And I dont know why.

**DBPasswordEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PasswordEntity",schema = "pwdmanager")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "password_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DBPasswordEntity extends DBMetaDataEntity implements Serializable {

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "password")
    private Set<DBExtendEntity> extend;

    @Transient
    public void addExtend(DBExtendEntity ex)
    {
        if(extend == null)
        {
            extend = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        }
        extend.add(ex);
    }

   }
```

**DBExtendEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ExtendEntity",schema = "pwdmanager")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "extend_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DBExtendEntity extends DBMetaDataEntity implements Serializable{

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "password", referencedColumnName = "Password_ID")
    private DBPasswordEntity password;  
}
```

**DBMetaDataEntity**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "pwd_type")
@Table(name = "MetaDataEntity",schema = "pwdmanager")
@Data
public abstract class DBMetaDataEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DML_ART", nullable = false)
    private String dml_art ="INSERT";
}
```

**SQL-Filter-Operation**

```
@Transactional
public interface PasswordRepository  extends JpaRepository<DBPasswordEntity,String> {

    @Query(value="SELECT pwd FROM DBPasswordEntity pwd WHERE pwd.dml_art <> 'DELETE' AND pwd.extend.id IN (SELECT  ext.id FROM DBExtendEntity ext where ext.dml_art <> 'DELETE')")
    List<DBPasswordEntity> findAll_DML_ART();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by switching to Hibernate.

**My updatet POM**

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>${jta.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Filter in a subclass**

```
 FROM DBPasswordEntity pwd WHERE pwd.mdae_dml_art <> 'DELETE' AND pwd.usre_user.usre_username = 'ABC' AND pwd.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM DBPasswordEntity pwd2 WHERE pwd2.mdae_rev_ID = pwd.mdae_rev_ID)"
```

Execute the query:

```
this.session.createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
```

The full example with all configuration for Hibernate at:
https://github.com/dominikLudwig/Passwordmanager

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...